# Single Sign On for for websites hosted on different domain

Tags: php, single-sign-on

this is Emon. I have 2 websites and both are built in PHP. Now I'm trying to join these two websites which are mywebsite.com and mywebsite.live so that my users can log in to mywebsite.com and click on the live icon which is linked to mywebsite.live and will be instantly signed in, as it would be more convenient for customers to just log in once and they can navigate between the sites.

How do I create a single sign on page for login to both the side? For ie: If my users log in to mywebsite.com and press the live icon(I already have a live icon which redirects to mywebsite.live) it will take my users to mywebsite.live and automatically login as the same user. Please help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SSO solution that I've implemented here works as follows:

There is a master domain, login.mydomain.com with the script

master_login.php that manages the logins.

Each client domain has the script client_login.php

All the domains have a shared user session database.

When the client domain requires the user to be logged in, it redirects to the

master domain (login.mydomain.com/master_login.php). If the user has not signed in

to the master it requests authentication from the user (ie. display login page).

After the user is authenticated it creates a session in a database. If the user is

already authenticated it looks up their session id in the database.

The master domain returns to the client domain 
(client.mydomain.com/client_login.php) passing the session id.

The client domain creates a cookie storing the session id from the master. The client can find out the logged in user by querying the shared database using the session id.
Notes:

The session id is a unique global identifier generated with algorithm from RFC 4122
The master_login.`enter code here`php will only redirect to domains in its whitelist
The master and clients can be in different top level domains. Eg. client1.abc.com, client2.xyz.com, login.mydomain.com

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Just clarify me one more thing that, do you use any service provider like auth0 or Okta or OpenID Connect?? Please let me know. Thanks